# _curses.error: add_wch() returned an error

Tags: python, curses, roguelike

I have the following code rendering the display for my roguelike game. It includes rendering the map.

```
  def render_all(self):
    for y in range(self.height):
      for x in range(self.width):
        wall = self.map.lookup(x,y).blocked
        if wall:
          self.main.addch(y, x, "#")
        else:
          self.main.addch(y, x, ".")
    for thing in self.things:
      draw_thing(thing)
```

It errors out every time. I think it's because it's going off the screen, but the height and width variables are coming from self.main.getmaxyx(), so it shouldn't do that, right? What am I missing? Python 3.4.3 running in Ubuntu 14.04 should that matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's expected behavior.  Python uses ncurses, which does this because other implementations do this.

In the [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html) for `addch`:

> The  **`addch`**,  **`waddch`**, **`mvaddch`** and **`mvwaddch`** routines put the
>          character *`ch`* into the given window at its  current  window
>          position,  which  is then advanced.  They are analogous to
>          **`putchar`** in stdio(3).  If the advance is at the right  margin:
>
> - The cursor automatically wraps to the beginning of the
>            next line.
> - At the bottom of the current scrolling region, and  if
>            **`scrollok`**  is enabled, the scrolling region is scrolled
>            up one line.
> - If **`scrollok`** is not enabled, writing a character at the
>            lower  right  margin  succeeds.   However, *an error is
>            returned because it is not possible to wrap to  a  new
>            line*

Python's curses binding has [`scrollok`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.scrollok). To add characters without scrolling, you would call it with a "false" parameter, e.g.,

```
self.main.scrollok(0)
```

If you do not want to scroll, you can use a try/catch block, like this:

```
import curses

def main(win):
  for y in range(curses.LINES):
    for x in range(curses.COLS):
      try:
        win.addch(y, x, ord('.'))
      except (curses.error):
        pass
      curses.napms(1)
      win.refresh()
  ch = win.getch()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: So what do I do if I want to put a character at the lower right margin without scrolling?

Comment: No advice @Thomas Dickey? How do I write to the bottom-right margin without crashing? Wrap it in a try/except clause? But what if there is another, legitimate curses error?

Comment: `addch` would return an error if the window is a null pointer, but that's unlikely.  A try/catch around `addch` seems your only solution (making a special case to do this only at the lower-right corner would add clutter).

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to use try/except but it's not working. Here's the code:

    try:
      self.main.addch(thing.y, thing.x, thing.disp,
                    curses.color_pair(self.color_palette[thing.color]))
    except _curses.error: pass

It says that _curses is not defined. But when I run it outside the block, the error message it gives me is _curses.error: add_wch() returned ERR. ERR doesn't work either.